# Thymeleaf context URL processing - how to add language code to context-relative URLs (Spring + Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, url, filter, thymeleaf

I have written request filter and locale resolver for getting language code from URL. (for example: DOMAIN/en/, DOMAIN/cs/)

However, I don't know how to change programmatically the context path that Thymeleaf uses for its context-relative URLs (@{/css/main.css}).

For example, if on page with address "DOMAIN/en/test/" is following code

```
<a th:href="@{/test2/}">TEST 2</a>
```

it points at

```
DOMAIN/test2/
```

instead of

```
DOMAIN/en/test2/
```

I thought it would be good to create some filter that edits the URL before it goes to Thymeleaf templates, but I don't have any idea how.

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: I would not add the language to the url, you can store it in the user session, and load the resources, css, i18 as you need, but doesnt modify the urls just because the user change the language

Comment: I think that as far as SEO is concerned its recommented to have different URLs for different languages... Lots of sites use it. Isn't there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution that suits my expectations.

I just wanted to insert language code after context path (example.com/CONTEXT_PATH/CONTROLLER -> example.com/CONTEXT_PATH/**LANGUAGE_CODE**/CONTROLLER) for Thymeleaf templates, so I can still use Thymeleaf's url expression @{/controller}.

I have url filter that removes language code and adds it to request's attributes, so I have just edited the response's encodeURL method and it works as I wanted:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(newUrl).forward(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
    @Override
    public String encodeURL(String url) {
        String contextPath = getServletContext().getContextPath();
        if (url.startsWith(contextPath))
            url = new StringBuilder(url).insert(contextPath.length(), "/" + getLocale().getLanguage()).toString();
        return super.encodeURL(url);
    }
});
```

Anyway, thanks for your answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put urls in message resource files:

```
<a th:href="@{#{orders.details.localized_url}(id=${order.id})}">
```

as described in: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Or return appropriate template view for example:

```
    @RequestMapping("/localized/**")
    public String getTemplateView(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        //path = /localized/en/mypage
        return mypage_en.html;// or relative location in the configured folder
    }
```

I like the first one better